# how to show list from highest to lowest in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a list
final List first = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
i want to show it like 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 when user clicks on a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sort method:

```
 final list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  list.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
 print(list);
```

this will print [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

sort documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/List/sort.html

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
List<int> list2 = list.reversed.toList();
```

or

```
List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].reversed.toList();
```